# How to read a file containing more than one record type within?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file that contains 3 types of records, each with different quantity of columns.

I know the structure of each record type and that the rows are always of type1 first, then type2 and type 3 at the end, but I don't know how many rows of each record type there are.

The first 4 characters of each row define the record type of that row.

CSV Example:

```
typ1,John,Smith,40,M,Single
typ1,Harry,Potter,22,M,Married
typ1,Eva,Adams,35,F,Single
typ2,2020,08,16,A
typ2,2020,09,02,A
typ3,Chevrolet,FC101TT,2017
typ3,Toyota,CE972SY,2004
```

How can I read It with Pandas? It doesn't matter if I have to read one record type each time.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a pandas solution.

First we must read the csv file in a way that pandas keeps the entires lines in one cell each. We do that by simply using a wrong separator, such as the 'at' symbol `'@'`. It can be whatever we want, since we guarantee **it won't ever appear in our data file**.

```
wrong_sep = '@'
right_sep = ','

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', sep=wrong_sep).iloc[:, 0]
```

The `.iloc[:, 0]` is used as a quick way to convert a DataFrame into a Series.

Then we use a loop to select the rows that belong to each data structure based on their starting characters. Now we use the "right separator" (probably a comma `','`) to split the desired data into real DataFrames.

```
starters = ['typ1', 'typ2', 'typ3']
detected_dfs = dict()

for start in starters:
    _df = df[df.str.startswith(start)].str.split(right_sep, expand=True)

    detected_dfs[start] = _df
```

And here you go. If we print the resulting DataFrames, we get:

```
      0      1       2   3  4        5
0  typ1  Harry  Potter  22  M  Married
1  typ1    Eva   Adams  35  F   Single

      0     1   2   3  4
2  typ2  2020  08  16  A
3  typ2  2020  09  02  A

      0          1        2     3
4  typ3  Chevrolet  FC101TT  2017
5  typ3     Toyota  CE972SY  2004
```

Let me know if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

**Not Pandas:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

filename2 = 'Types.txt'

with open(filename2) as dataLines:
    nL = dataLines.read().splitlines()
    defDList = defaultdict(list)
    subs = ['typ1','typ2','typ3']
    dataReadLines = [defDList[i].append(j) for i in subs for j in nL if i in j]
    # dataReadLines = [i for i in nL]
    print(defDList)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'typ1': ['typ1,John,Smith,40,M,Single', 'typ1,Harry,Potter,22,M,Married', 'typ1,Eva,Adams,35,F,Single'], 'typ2': ['typ2,2020,08,16,A', 'typ2,2020,09,02,A'], 'typ3': ['typ3,Chevrolet,FC101TT,2017', 'typ3,Toyota,CE972SY,2004']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `skiprows` parameter of pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method to skip the rows you are not interested in for a particular record type. The following gives you a dictionary `dfs` of dataframes for each type. An advantage is that records of the same types don't necessarily have to be adjacent to each other in the csv file.

For larger files you might want to adjust the code such that the file is only read once instead of twice.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

indices = defaultdict(list)
types = ['typ1', 'typ2', 'typ3']
filename = 'test.csv'

with open(filename) as csv:
    for idx, line in enumerate(csv.readlines()):
        for typ in types:
            if line.startswith(typ):
                indices[typ].append(idx)

dfs = {typ: pd.read_csv(filename, header=None,
                        skiprows=lambda x: x not in indices[typ])
       for typ in types}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as a CSV file using the CSV reader. The reader fortunately does not care about line formats:

```
import csv
with open("yourfile.csv") as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile))
```

Collect the rows with the same first element and build a dataframe of them:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(v) for _,v in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0])]
```

You've got a list of three dataframes (or as many as necessary).

```
dfs[1]
#      0     1   2   3  4
#0  typ2  2020  08  16  A
#1  typ2  2020  09  02  A
```